# Did Anne Rice portray Dracula in a work of fiction?

Tags: anne-rice

I'm curious if Anne Rice ever featured Dracula in a work of fiction, i.e. in her vampire novels or in a short story?  If not, why?

I haven't read all of her vampire novels, but I Googled around and reviewed a list of [characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Vampire_Chronicles_characters) and saw no mention of him.

Comment: By "portrayed", you mean "featured" I presume? Otherwise the imagery is kind of... giggle-inducing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. She has not.

Her Vampire Chronicles books

- Interview with the Vampire (1976)
- The Vampire Lestat (1985)
- The Queen of the Damned (1988)
- The Tale of the Body Thief    (1992)
- Memnoch the Devil (1995)
- The Vampire Armand (1998)
- Merrick (2000)
- Blood and Gold (2001)
- Blackwood Farm (2002)
- Blood Canticle (2003)
- Prince Lestat (2014)
- Prince Lestat and the Realms of Atlantis (2016)

None of which feature the character Dracula. Dracula is not an Anne Rice character - he doesn't exist in Anne Rice's world, or if he did, it would only be as he exists with us, through books. Dracula's weaknesses as a vampire which are said in the book to be shared with all other vampires are not characteristic to Anne Rice's vampires. For one Dracula does not cast a shadow nor does he appear in mirrors. Both things any vampire from the Anne Rice world can do. Below are some excerpts from Wikipedia

> He does not cast a shadow or have a reflection from mirrors. He is
>   immune to conventional means of attack; a sailor tries to stab him in
>   the back with a knife, but the blade goes through his body as though
>   it is air. The Count can defy gravity to a certain extent and
>   possesses superhuman agility, able to climb vertical surfaces upside
>   down in a reptilian manner. He can travel onto "unhallowed" ground
>   such as the graves of suicides and those of his victims. He has
>   powerful hypnotic, telepathic and illusionary abilities. He also has
>   the ability to "within limitations" vanish and reappear elsewhere at
>   will. If he knows the path, he can come out from anything or into
>   anything regardless of how close it is bound even if it is fused with
>   fire.
>
> He can command animals such as rats, owls, bats, moths, foxes and
>   wolves.
>
> Dracula can also manipulate the weather and, within his range, is able
>   to direct the elements, such as storms, fog and mist.
>   Dracula can shapeshift at will, able to grow and become small, his
>   featured forms in the novel being that of a bat, a wolf, a large dog
>   and a fog or mist. When the moonlight is shining, he can travel as
>   elemental dust within its rays. He is able to pass through tiny cracks
>   or crevices while retaining his human form or in the form of a vapour

Granted some of these Lestat could do, but only because he is Lestat and he is an especially strong vampire with extra supernatural abilities. It is extraordinary for a vampire in Anne Rice's world to have these abilities, it's the norm in the Dracula world. There are other things you can find like Lestat&co did not have to sleep in coffins and all the rest of it...

Dracula and Anne Rice do not belong to the same universe.